# What is the angle $\epsilon_{cl}$ in this diagram?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-physics

Here is an image showing the geometric significance of $\epsilon_{cl}$. To me it looks like the angle between the tangent of the underside of the trailing edge and horizontal (V infinity).

[image: Definition of the angle]

Here is a formula for $\epsilon_{cl}$:

$$ \epsilon_{cl} = \frac{1.62 C_{L_w}}{\pi A} $$

$C_{L_w}$ is the coefficient of lift of the wing and $A$ is the aspect ratio.

Comment: What is the source of the image (unless you created it)?

Comment: Estimation of aircraft aerodynamic center for
conventional, canard, or three-surface aircraft v0.9
Based on Dr. Jan Roskam’s Aircraft Design Series

Comment: its from this document, I don't know if you can find it online. Its about the multhopp method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the *downwash angle*. Consider it an angle by which the wing deflects the airflow behind it.

Traditionally, this angle is designated $\epsilon$. Why the $cl$ index I don't know; perhaps it reinforces its direct dependency on the wing lift coefficient, as you can see from the formula; or that this is the 'pure' downwash *only* dependent on the wing. In fact, every document should have a Nomenclature section which explains the designations.

Apart from $C_L$ and $A$, the effective downwash angle will depend on the distance from the wing and spanwise location. Typically, the point of interest is the tailplane: downwash reduces its effective angle of attack. The coefficient $1.62$ probably accounts for the tail location ($z_h$ etc.), but you need to double check how this $\epsilon$ is used. (You will find different coefficients in the literature).

Obviously, this will affect trimming. But downwash also has a significant effect on stability, because it changes dynamically with lift. As the angle of attack / lift (of the wing) increases, downwash also increases. Therefore, the horizontal tail experiences a reduced variation of angles of attack compared to the wing. This is further complicated by the fact that this reduction is *delayed* by the time it takes for the airflow to reach the tail. Generally, these are positive effects, but they must be accounted for in stability analysis.

Comment: The cl stands for the centerline. The equation shows that this is the downwash angle and the factor 1.62 is normally 2 when wing and tail are in one plane. Here the T-tail reduces this factor to 1.62, as you say. +1.